# MS MVC 4(VB) -batch post to ajax with json string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm another newbie to Microsoft MVC.  I'm also using VB.NET.  I have a CRUD app when I'm trying to write a batch update.  Meaning loop though my HTML Table, find out if modified and POST to my MYSQL table.

I get two errors
1.) db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified in my controller says "entitiy type List'1 not in my model" 
2.) if I change one of my table fields to "EditorFor" because I want to edit that field my code doesn't pick up my changes only what was initially loaded to the table.

Any pointers would be appreciated

```
My MODEL

Namespace Models
Public Class Tickets
    <Display(name:="id")> Public Property id As Nullable(Of Integer)
    <Display(name:="status")> Public Property status As Nullable(Of Integer)
    <Display(name:="bug id")> Public Property bug_text_id As Nullable(Of     Integer)
    <Display(name:="build")> Public Property build As String
    <Display(name:="Summary")> Public Property summary As String
    <Display(name:="priority")> Public Property priority As Nullable(Of Integer)
End Class



My CONTROLLER VB
<HttpPost> _
Public Function Update(model As List(Of EFMySQLCrud10.Models.Tickets)) As ActionResult
    '
    Dim pta_Value = New Models.Tickets
    For Each item In model
        If item.id = item.id Then
            pta_Value = item
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified
                db.SaveChanges()
            End If

            'Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Return View(pta_Value)
    Return RedirectToAction("Index")
End Function
```

MY JS which is in my VIEW for now
JS in my VIEW
window.gbDataURL = '@Url.Action("Update", "PTA")';

```
    function batch_Save() {


            var table = document.getElementById('results');


       //setup model array
            model = [];


            ////
            //loop view table for values
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                var str_priority_id = (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
                var str_priority = (table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
                var str_status = (table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
                var str_bugId = (table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);
                var str_build = (table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML);


                //build jSON model
                var item = { id: str_priority_id, priority: str_priority };
                model.push(item);
            }


            $.ajax({
                url: gbDataURL,
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    //call is successfully completed and we got result in data
                    alert("ajax call was successful")

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error
                    alert(xhr.responseText);

                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Long since forgotten VB but (1) whats the point of `If item.id = item.id Then` which is always true (2) whats the point of `If ModelState.IsValid Then` in each loop - if its invalid in the first iteration its invalid in every iteration! - just test it once before the loop (3) Your model is a collection not the item in the collection, so `db.Entry(model).State` would need to be `bb.Entry(item).State` (and you can delete all the `pta_Value` stuff)

Comment: As for using `EditorFor()` in a table cell, you need to show your view, but `.innerHTML` wont return the value of the input that `EditorFor()` generates - it will return something like `<input type="text" name=".." value="..." />`.  Debug your code!

Comment: Here's what I have now